# what causes system calls in linux to run at elevated permissions

Tags: c, linux

In linux, utilities can be assigned certain user/groups and thereby limiting access to them. I get that, but how does linux apply permissions at system call level. For example, if i try to change the scheduling policy or raise my thread's priority via pthread_setschedparam, the call will fail, unless i run my process as root.

So my question is what component in linux is responsible for applying permissions to system calls? If i understand the component responsible for permissions at system call level, then i can request system admin to grant my user access to certain system calls. Maybe the permissions are not at system calls, but at certain actions such as changing thread priority. What do i need to tell the system admin, so he can give me selective access to such actions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The source-code from the kernel looks like this:

Lets take `settimeofday()` for example which sets the kernel time, which will require root permissions

There is a function `security_settime()` which checks the security to set the time

It calls `cap_settime(`) which uses the `capable()` function

`capable(int capability)` [kernel/capability.c]

This checks if the current user has the capability to do certain things, and in the set-time case, that cap is `CAP_SYS_TIME`

---

```
int do_sys_settimeofday(const struct timespec *tv, const struct timezone *tz)
{
    static int firsttime = 1;
    int error = 0;

    if (tv && !timespec_valid(tv))
        return -EINVAL;

    error = security_settime(tv, tz);
    if (error)
        return error;

    if (tz) {
        sys_tz = *tz;
        update_vsyscall_tz();
        if (firsttime) {
            firsttime = 0;
            if (!tv)
                warp_clock();
        }
    }
    if (tv)
        return do_settimeofday(tv);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And to answer the question of how to give access, one can use e.g. `setcap` to grant these capabilities to a certain executable.

Comment: setcap is at an individual file level. If i recompile my process, which replaces an old file with new file, will these still be applicable? Is there a similar command that can be applied at user level ?

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty self-explanatory. A system call is a call to the kernel, so the kernel is responsible of applying a security policy to some system calls.

Since Linux 2.6, the Linux Security Modules (LSM) framework has been in place to allow the development of modules to control certain accesses in the kernel. The most commonly known implementation using LSM is probably [SELinux](http://selinuxproject.org). Another known implementation is [AppArmor](http://wiki.apparmor.net/).

Additionally, some [`capabilities(7)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/capabilities.7.html) built in the 2.6+ kernels allow you to control whether certain some privileged system calls can be done by unprivileged users.

Answer (score 1):

In the specific case of pthread_setschedparam(3) the answer depends on the Linux kernel version and is somehow complex. Have a look at the section *Privileges and resource limits* of the manpage `sched_setscheduler(2)` which is referenced by `pthread_setschedparam(3)`.

In general the permission to use some system calls may be governed by the caller's `capabilites(7)`

Comment: You should really read the sched_setscheduler(2) manpage! There it says "In Linux kernels before 2.6.12, only privileged (CAP_SYS_NICE) processes can set a nonzero static priority (i.e., set a real-time scheduling policy)." And further "Since Linux 2.6.12, the RLIMIT_RTPRIO resource limit defines a ceiling on an unprivileged process's static priority for the SCHED_RR and SCHED_FIFO policies". HTH.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as the CPU jumps into kernel space, it is effectively running as `root`[*].

That is, it works exactly opposite the way you're thinking of from the user perspective: instead of running as a normal user and having to somehow elevate yourself to `root` to access files/devices you normally can't, kernel space code is always running as `root` and has to make user privilege checks to ensure that it restricts what it does on the user's behalf to only those operations allowed to that user.

---

[*] [MAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandatory_access_control) systems like SELinux modify this, of course.